# Getting 'failed creating virtual environment' error when amplify push

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, aws-amplify

Anyone encounter this problem before? I can't amplify push to deploy my aws function and api.

This is the error I getting: [image]

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your current local configuration, but I managed to fix this issue by editing my Pipfile to use python 3.9 instead of python 3.8.